# How I can corrupt a data base page and again restore the same

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, corruption

I want to corrupt a database page, and restore the same page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

I love this question!

To demo, I'm going to use a local copy of the Fitness database from the [Stack Overflow](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) data dump.

First, make sure your database is in FULL recovery, and take a full and log backup.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [FITNESS] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS.bak' 
WITH FORMAT, INIT, STATS = 1, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM
GO

BACKUP LOG [FITNESS] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS.trn' 
WITH FORMAT, INIT, STATS = 1, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM
GO
```

Next, head into your database, and grab a page to corrupt. You should be able to use this query on 2012 plus. It creates a simple dynamic block with `DBCC WRITEPAGE`

```
USE FITNESS

SELECT TOP 1
    N'DBCC WRITEPAGE (' 
  + CAST([dddpa].[database_id] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N', '
  + CAST([dddpa].[allocated_page_file_id] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N', '
  + CAST([dddpa].[allocated_page_page_id] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N', ' 
  + N'0' + N', ' 
  + N'4' + N', ' 
  + N'0x0000008A' 
  + N', 1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS' AS [cmd]
FROM
    [sys].[dm_db_database_page_allocations](DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS [dddpa]
WHERE [dddpa].[allocated_page_page_id] > 250;
```

After that, you'll need to set your database to `SINGLE_USER` and corrupt the page

```
ALTER DATABASE FITNESS SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

DBCC WRITEPAGE ( INSERT YOUR DBCC WRITEPAGE COMMAND HERE )

ALTER DATABASE FITNESS SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Remember to take note of which page you're overwriting. For me, it was page 280. Now I can run a restore sequence like this:

```
USE master

RESTORE DATABASE FITNESS
PAGE='1:280' 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS.bak' 
WITH NORECOVERY;

RESTORE LOG FITNESS 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS.trn' 
WITH NORECOVERY;

BACKUP LOG [FITNESS] 
TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS_1.trn' 
WITH FORMAT, INIT, STATS = 1, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM, NORECOVERY

RESTORE LOG FITNESS 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Backup\FITNESS_1.trn' 
WITH NORECOVERY;

RESTORE DATABASE FITNESS
WITH RECOVERY;
```

If you want more practice, I highly recommend [Steve Stedman's database corruption challenge](http://stevestedman.com/2015/04/introducing-the-database-corruption-challenge-dbcc-week-1-challenge/).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a good backup of your current testing database.  This will be required when you need to restore back to a good version.  Following the instructions in [How to Deliberately Corrupt a SQL Server Database Using DBCC WRITEPAGE](https://rule30.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/how-to-deliberately-corrupt-sql-server-database-using-dbcc-writepage/)

There is a bold disclaimer at the very top of that post

**Warning: Do not carry out any of the instructions in this post anywhere near a production server or even a development server with valuable databases on it. Following these instructions incorrectly could severely damage either a single database or an entire SQL Server instance**

After you have completed your testing, restore the testing database from the backup you created.

Comment: "Oh, did I run this in production?!?!?!"